# Least Squares Plane using Matricies

Tags: linear-algebra

For a Least Squares solution to a 2D set of coordinates, the formula is:

$X^T\,X\,\vec b = X^Ty$ (where $X^T$ denotes $X$ transpose)
(for: $y = B_0 + B_1x + B_2x^2$)
**where:**
$X$:        $b$:       $y$:
[$1$  $x_1$]  [$B_0$]  [$y_1$]
[$1$  $x_2$]  [$B_1$]  [$y_2$]
[$1$  $x_3$]  [$B_2$]  [$y_3$]
[...  ...]           [... ]

**My question is:**
What do I need to change in order for me to use least squares to solve for a 3d surface?
Also, what would my equation look like? $y = B_0 + B_1x_1 + B_2x_2 + B_3{x_1}^2 + B_4{x_2}^2$ ?
Thanks a million.

Comment: What are you asking for?  Are you looking for the vector with the least squares difference from a plane or something else?  By 3-D surface, do you mean a plane in 3 dimensions or a 3-dimensional hyperplane?

Comment: Yes. I want to know how I can find an equation with three parameters, say x y z, that is an approximation based on a set of data points. The purpose being that I have a 2d space of weighted values and I would like to generate a function rule with input (x,y coordinates) and output the value z such that z is the least squares solution based on the input. Preferably, I would like to know how I can modify the matricies and/or equation above to do this.

Comment: None of those were yes/no questions! Anyway, I think I understand what you're asking for.

Comment: Just as a note: My input is values of an entire plane. The input = {s | s = (x, y), x in plane's width & y in plane's length}

Comment: The way you asked things in your question, it seems you're a little confused about a) how matrix multiplication works, and b) what it is you're looking for.  Remember, you can find $A\,B$ only if the number of columns in $A$ matches the number of rows in $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to clarify, you're looking for the best approximation of the form $z=f(x,y)=a_xx+a_yy+a_0$ in $xyz$-space for a set of $x,y,z$ data points.  In order to do that, we begin by supposing that there is an exact solution.  If that were the case, our system of equations would look like this:
$$
a_0+a_xx_1+a_yy_1=z_1\\
a_0+a_xx_2+a_yy_2=z_2\\
\vdots
$$
and so forth.  We can rewrite this in matrix-form as follows:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & x_1 & y_1 \\ 
1 & x_2 & y_2 \\ 
\, & \vdots & \, \\ 
1 & x_n & y_n
\end{array}
\right]
\,\left[
\begin{array}{c}
a_0\\
a_x\\
a_y
\end{array}
\right]=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
z_1\\
z_2\\
\vdots\\
z_n
\end{array}
\right]
$$
From there, getting the least squares solution simply a matter of applying the same logic as before.  Setting
$$
A=
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & x_1 & y_1 \\ 
1 & x_2 & y_2 \\ 
\, & \vdots & \, \\ 
1 & x_n & y_n
\end{array}
\right];
\vec x=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
a_0\\
a_x\\
a_y
\end{array}
\right];
\vec y =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
z_1\\
z_2\\
\vdots\\
z_n
\end{array}
\right]
$$
we have
$$
A^TA \vec x = A^T\vec y
$$
And must solve for $\vec x$.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't imagine it would be so simple!

Comment: Note, this is only for a plane.  If you want to add $x^2$ and $y^2$ terms into your equation, you could do that by a similar method using a matrix of 5 columns.  The easiest way to do any problem like this is to start with the (generally inconsistent) system of equations, and follow through as I did here.